# Isolated Azure function returning IActionResult doesn't work with multiple output bindings

Tags: c#, azure, .net-8.0, azure-functions-isolated

I've got some Azure functions that I've been migrating from .NET6 in-process model to .NET8 isolated model. These functions are coded to return `IActionResult` objects rather than `HttpResponseData`.

One set of these functions return a single `IActionResult` from the function, and I have these working as expected in .NET8 with the isolated model. But another set uses multiple output bindings - One is the HTTP response and one is an event published to an event grid topic.

To achieve this multiple output binding in the isolated model, I used [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#multiple-output-bindings) from Microsoft. My output class, looks slightly different than the one in the MS example because I am using `IActionResult` instead of `HttpResponseData`:

```
public class OutputBindingType
{
    public IActionResult HttpResponse { get; set; }
        
    [EventGridOutput(TopicEndpointUri = "SoftwareApplicationsTopicUri", TopicKeySetting = "SoftwareApplicationsTopicKey")]
    public EventGridEvent EventGridResponse { get; set; }
}
```

My HTTP-triggered Azure function using this output type looks like:

```
public async Task<OutputBindingType> CreateSoftwareApplication(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "softwareApplications")] 
    HttpRequest req)
{
    ...
}
```

When I try to run this migrated code, the output binding to the event grid works as expected: Events are successfully published. But the HTTP response isn't working. The contents of the `IActionResult` object seem to be ignored. I have error objects as well as OK objects with an object representing response bodies. No matter what I send here, the result seems to be an HTTP `200` status code with an empty response body.

Is there something special that needs to be done to make include an IAction-based response to an Azure function with an HTTP trigger? Or do I need to refactor all of these functions to remove the use of `IActionResult` in favor of `HttpResponseData`?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I found a workaround on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/2079#issuecomment-1893639361) on the "azure-functions-dotnet-worker" project.

It appears that the property `public HttpResponse HttpResponse` in whatever class you're returning as your multiple output binding from the function is required to be the `HttpResponse` type, and the name must be `HttpResponse`.

Borrowing from the workaround posted by [Joe Harvey](https://github.com/HARVS1789UK-VAIIE) at the link above, I implemented a MultiReponse class like this, to conform to those requirements:

```
public MultiResponse(string queueMessage, HttpRequest req, HttpStatusCode code, object payload = null)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queueMessage))
        Messages = new string[] { queueMessage };
    else
        Messages = Array.Empty<string>();
    if (req != null)
    {
        HttpResponse = req.HttpContext.Response;
        
        HttpResponse.StatusCode = (int)code;
        if (payload != null)
        {
            HttpResponse.WriteAsJsonAsync(payload).Wait();
            HttpResponse.Headers.Append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        }
        else
        {
            HttpResponse.Headers.Append("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=utf-8");
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to pass in the `HttpRequest req` object from your HttpTrigger function, use that to generate the HttpResponse, and then fill in the code and data however you'd like.

You could probably alter it to take an IActionResponse object and parse out the code, content and headers from that as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Not a great Azure user , but I know that it does not do Simultaneous multi-tasking like Google Colab could do. Even though it might do heavy loaded tasks , it treats all lightweight tasks like HTTP analysing like they never existed.

Fun fact, The EventGridOutput property is decorated with attributes, TopicEndpointUri and TopicKeySetting, which are used to configure the Event Grid output binding for writing events to a custom topic instead. Plus, CreateSoftwareApplication is a function that is asynchronous to HTTP post request.
In short,
***All you need is to authorise and add HttpRequest as a parameter.The return type of the function is a Task that resolves to an object of type OutputBindingType*** . Rest you can handle things yourself.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).